# Marketing Cloud SDK iOS - Inbox Messages not cleared/deleted when user logout

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, mobilepush-ios

All messages received while authenticated remain on the Inbox after the user signs out and the unread messages icon is still displayed on the app icon when the user is signed out.

Is there a way to clear or reset the inbox data when user logout?

Answer (score 1):

There is no "log out" functionality within the SDK and there is no non-destructive way to hide the data.

You could "gate" the call to `getMessages()` based on the logged in/logged out state of your application and return an empty list when the user is logged out rather than returning the actual result from the SDK.

Comment: the problem is badge number displayed in app icon which I couldnt cleared.   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];

Comment: Even after user logout, badge number increments if i leave the application in anonymous mode

Comment: Set the badge manually and make sure it gets updated in your service extension?  Creativity will be your friend.